# Zapier: Update google spread sheet row

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I have tried to updated google sheet row by giving a value to look up and I got an updated row in google sheet. But now I have to update row using dynamic value.

Earlier Approach:

sheet column => Total => Lookup value was 'Last 7 Days'

What I want now:

sheet column => Total => Lookup value will be like 'Sunday, July 19, 2020'

And each day we will be able to see new value in each row of Total column.

**So how can I handle this in Zapier?**

Google Sheet:
[image]

Zap Steps:
[image]

Zap Sheet Lookup Detail:
[image]

Comment: Could you give a bit more information on your workflow? What's Triggering this? How often will that sheet be updated?

Comment: @OwariJules I have written a python script and the script hit the webhook url provided by zap and then zap catch the data and populates in the google sheet and this process runs daily.